# Is this operator Hermitian? Commutator of non-Hermitian operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator, density-operator

In the derivation of a Master Equation, I am left with two additional terms:

$$ \sigma_j [\sigma^{\dagger}_k,\rho] - [\rho, \sigma_k]\sigma_j^{\dagger} \quad ,$$

where $\sigma_j = |g\rangle \langle e|_j$ and $\sigma_j^{\dagger}=|e\rangle\langle g|_j$ are spin lowering and raising operators on subsystem $j$ and $\rho$ is the density matrix. The second term is the Hermitian conjugate of the first and therefore, if the first term is Hermitian the result is zero.

Is there any way to tell if $$\sigma_j[\sigma^{\dagger}_k,\rho]$$ is Hermitian? Further to this, to make the question more general, can the  commutator of an arbitrary density matrix with non-hermitian raising/lowering operators be expressed in a different form?

Comment: What is $\rho$, a density matrix? What is the Hilbert space under consideration? Could you define the $\sigma$ operators explicitly, please?

Comment: @TobiasFünke Yes. It is the density matrix describing the atomic subspace of N two level systems.

Comment: @TobiasFünke The pauli operators are defined as: $\sigma_j = (|g><e|)_j$ on subsystem j. The action on all other subsystems is identity.

Comment: I see. Is $\rho$ arbitrary or does it have a special form? It would be nice if you include all of this in the question. BTW: use \langle and  \rangle to produce e.g. $\sigma_j= |g\rangle\langle e|_j$

Comment: Can  you write explicitly the generic N=2 ρ in your basis?

Comment: @TobiasFünke  I am deriving an equation for $\dot{\rho}$. These 2 terms remain in what is otherwise a non-diagonal Master equation (hence why I would like them to be zero). So $\rho$ is generic, and so I believe for $N = 2$  has the form $\rho = \sum_{i,j,k,l} c_{i,j,k,l} |i,j\rangle\langle k,l|$. Where $i,j,k,l \in \{g,e\}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the operator is not hermitian in general; it suffices to give a concrete counter example. Consider $h\cong \mathbb C^2$, $H:=\otimes^N h$ for $N\geq 2$ and denote by $\{|e\rangle,|g\rangle\}$ some orthonormal basis on $h$. Define
$$\rho:=\rho_1 \otimes\rho_2\otimes\ldots\otimes \rho_N \tag{1},$$

for some density matrices $\rho_\ell$ on $h$ for $\ell=1,2,\ldots,N$
and

$$\sigma_j:=\underbrace{\mathbb I\otimes \mathbb I\otimes \ldots\otimes \overbrace{\sigma}^{j-\mathrm{th\, factor}}\otimes \mathbb I \otimes \ldots \otimes \mathbb I}_{N-\mathrm{factors}} \quad , \tag 2 $$

where $\sigma:=|g\rangle\langle e|$ and $\mathbb I$ denotes the identity operator on $h$.

---

To proceed, we compute (here for $1\leq j<k\leq N$):

$$ \sigma_j \,[\sigma^\dagger_k,\rho] = \rho_1\otimes \rho_2 \otimes \ldots \otimes \sigma\rho_j\otimes \ldots\otimes [\sigma^\dagger,\rho_k]\otimes \ldots \otimes \rho_N  \quad . \tag{3}$$

Choosing $\rho_j=\rho_k=|e\rangle\langle e|$ then yields

$$   \sigma_j \,[\sigma^\dagger_k,\rho] = \rho_1\otimes \rho_2 \otimes \ldots \otimes \sigma \otimes \ldots\otimes - \sigma^\dagger \otimes \ldots \otimes \rho_N  \tag {4} \quad ,$$

which is clearly not hermitian.